# How to create dependency injection for testing QTcpSocket?

Tags: c++, qt, dependency-injection, qtestlib

I'm trying to write unit tests for a Qt5 application that I wrote, but I'm stumped about how to handle the classes that involve networking.  My main class includes a QTcpServer subclass, which overrides QTcpServer::incomingConnection to create a ClientConnection object and hands it off to a thread:

```
void NetworkServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    QThread* clientThread = new QThread();
    ClientConnection* clientConnection = new ClientConnection(socketDescriptor);
    clientConnection->moveToThread(clientThread);

    // connect signals & slots to ClientConnection (removed for clarity)

    connect(clientThread, &QThread::started, clientConnection, &ClientConnection::run);
    clientThread->start();
}
```

The ClientConnection class uses the socketDescriptor to open a new QTcpSocket in the dedicated thread, receives data from a client, and processes it.

```
ClientConnection::ClientConnection(int socketDescriptor, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent), socketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)
{
    tcpIncomingData = new QByteArray;
}

void ClientConnection::run()
{
    QTcpSocket socket;
    if(!socket.setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
           emit sig_error(socket.error());
           return;
       }

    if(socket.waitForReadyRead(5000)) {
        *tcpIncomingData = socket.readAll();
        qDebug() << "data received: " << tcpIncomingData;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "socket timed out!";
    }

    parseXmlData();

    socket.disconnectFromHost();
    socket.waitForDisconnected();
}
```

This class isn't finished but I want to start writing tests now.  My issue is how to handle the socketDescriptor.  I assume I need to use some sort of dependency injection, but I don't think that's feasible without creating an entire QTcpServer in the test case.

Testing network code must be common these days, so there must be a common way to handle this without including half of my application.  This seems like a general question, but if more detail about my specific application is required please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might want to define clean interfaces (meaning [pure abstract classes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes/Pure_Abstract_Classes)) for your classes, so that mocking and exchanging them wouldn't be a problem, say `IClientConnection`.

Then, you could declare your dependencies explicitly, i.e. either pass an `IClientConnection` factory or an instance of an `IClientConnection` to the `NetworkServer` constructor.

In your test, you can now implement a mock of `IClientConnection` and pass it or its factory (may also be an interface) to the constructor in the test. Perhaps, you might want to use a smart pointer ([shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or something native to Qt), so that automatic resource deallocation would minimize bugs.

If your software grows and you find yourself writing a lot of manual dependency injection, you might use a DI library. I've recently started a [review](http://ledentsov.de/2013/12/26/quest-for-a-cpp-dependency-injection-container-library-part-1-wallaroo-introduction/) of some of the available C++ DI libraries.

Finally, you might get far by mocking your dependencies using a mocking framework, such as [googlemock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/).

Comment: p.s. have you considered using a higher-level networking component?